# Simple way to load new files only into Redshift from S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

The documentation for the Redshift COPY command specifies two ways to choose files to load from S3, you either provide a base path and it loads all the files under that path, or you specify a manifest file with specific files to load.

However in our case, which I imagine is pretty common, the S3 bucket periodically receives new files with more recent data. We'd like to be able to load only the files that haven't already been loaded.

Given that there is a table stl_file_scan that logs all the files that have been loaded from S3, it would be nice to somehow exclude those that have successfully been loaded. This seems like a fairly obvious feature, but I can't find anything in the docs or online about how to do this.

Even the Redshift S3 loading template in AWS Data Pipeline appears to manage this scenario by loading all the data -- new and old -- to a staging table, and then comparing/upserting to the target table. This seems like an insane amount of overhead when we can tell up front from the filenames that a file has already been loaded.

I know we could probably move the files that have already been loaded out of the bucket, however we can't do that, this bucket is the final storage place for another process which is not our own.

The only alternative I can think of is to have some other process running that tracks files that have been successfully loaded to redshift, and then periodically compares that to the s3 bucket to determine the differences, and then writes the manifest file somewhere before triggering the copy process. But what a pain! We'd need a separate ec2 instance to run the process which would have it's own management and operational overhead.

There must be a better way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem,

S3 -- (Lambda Trigger on newly created Logs) -- Lambda -- Firehose -- Redshift

It works at any scale. With more load, more calls to Lambda, more data to firehose and everything taken care automatically.

If there are issues with the format of the file, you can configure dead letter queues, events will be sent there and you can reprocess once you fix lambda.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely this is the best approach nowadays. Things have gotten a lot better since I originally asked this (prior to lambda or firehose existing).

Answer (score 1):

Here I would like to mention some steps that includes process that how to load data in redshift.

1. Export local RDBMS data to flat files (Make sure you remove invalid
   characters, apply escape sequence during export).
2. Split files into 10-15 MB each to get optimal performance during
   upload and final Data load.
3. Compress files to `*.gz` format so you don’t end up with $1000
   surprise bill :) .. In my case Text files were compressed 10-20
   times.
4. List all file names to manifest file so when you issue COPY command
   to Redshift its treated as one unit of load.
5. Upload manifest file to Amazon S3 bucket.
6. Upload local `*.gz` files to Amazon S3 bucket.
7. Issue Redshift COPY command with different options.
8. Schedule file archiving from on-premises and S3 Staging area on AWS.
9. Capturing Errors, setting up restart ability if something fails
   Doing it easy way you can follow this link.

Answer (score 1):

AWS introduced a new feature to handle this case automatically. See [auto-copy feature](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-redshift-supports-auto-copy-amazon-s3/). It is still in preview state, but it looks like the custom solution won't be needed to load only new files directly from S3.

Answer (score 0):

In general compare of loaded files to existing on S3 files is a bad but possible practice. The common "industrial" practice is to use message queue between data producer and data consumer that actually loads the data. Take a look on RabbitMQ vs Amazon SQS and etc..

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would label this a bad practice. Granted if you have large numbers of files arriving at high frequency, then a comparison approach may not be feasible. However small numbers of files infrequently should work ok. Maintaining another 2 pieces of software/infrastructure, (message queue and a consumer/orchestrator), not to mention requiring the producer to submit messages to the queue, seems like an awful lot of overhead when your volumes are low.